# Asp.net Hyperlink control equivalent to <a href="#"></a>

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I wanted to define a HyperLink control in asp.net that produces html output similar to the following:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I agree with SLaks, but here you go

```
   <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
                  NavigateUrl="#"
                  Text=""
                  runat="server"/>
```

or you can alter the href using

```
hyperlink1.NavigateUrl = "#"; 
hyperlink1.Text = string.empty;
```

Comment: thanks I've tried this but here is the output: <a href="myPageUrl#"></a>, I don't need that myPageUrl chunk

Comment: `<a href="myPageUrl#"></a>` and `<a href="#"></a>` both go to the same place...?... Are you sure, I just tried the source says `<a id="hyperlink1" href="#"></a>`

Comment: Slaks answer is OK, but I was looking to doing this with server side controls

Comment: I realise this is old, but why would you want to use a server-side control for this? So you can add a tiny amount of extra server-side processing time for literally no gain?

Answer (score 10):

Just write `<a href="#"></a>`.

If that's what you want, you don't need a server-side control.

Comment: server side controls are useful in asp net events, like on databound of grids etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
hyperlink1.NavigateUrl = "#"; or
hyperlink1.attributes["href"] = "#"; or
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="#" runat="server" />
```

Comment: It's ancient history, but: 
(1) it's .Attributes - capitalization.
(2) setting the attribute is different from setting NavigateUrl, the latter expands to the url of the page the link is in with "#" on the end, the former gives you only "#".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the value on aspx page , Just enter `<a href='your link'>clickhere</a>`

If you are trying to achieve it via Code-Behind., Make use of the Hyperlink control

```
HyperLink hl1 = new HyperLink();
hl1.text="Click Here";
hl1.NavigateUrl="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp:Hyperlink
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access this as a server-side control (e.g. you want to add data attributes to a link, as I did), then there is a way to do what you want; however, you don't use the Hyperlink or HtmlAnchor controls to do it. Create a literal control and then add in "Your Text" as the text for the literal control (or whatever else you need to do that way). It's hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

**I solved this issue by typing**

```
     <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" href="#" Text="Some Text" runat="server"/>
```