# go to function on click on html tag <a>

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this code in default.aspx

```
<div id="mydiv">

</div>
```

and in default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mydiv.InnerHtml="<a href='#'>log out</a>";
}

protected void Log_out()
{
    Session["user"] = null;
}
```

how i can go to function onclick on html a tag

i try to add this

```
mydiv.InnerHtml="<a href='#' OnClick='Log_out'>log out</a>";
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: how can you access `mydiv` in code behind, its not a server side control. So how you are doing `mydiv.InnerHtml ....`

Comment: its working my brother i all the time use it

Comment: Have you considered using [ASP.NET HyperLink control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) element([SO post that can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745113/asp-net-hyperlink-control-eqivalent-to-a-href-a))?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing what the [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used for.

---

## HTML

```html
<div id="mydiv" runat="server"></div>
```

---

## C#

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lb = new LinkButton { Text = "log out" };
    lb.Click += (o, i) => { Session["user"] = null; };

    mydiv.Controls.Add(lb);
}
```

<sub>You will need import `using System;` and `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Also make changes to the following code..
mydiv.InnerHtml="< a href='#' onclick='Log_out()' >log out< /a>";

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute Logout method, which is server side method, then you need to use server side controls, like [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Then you can write:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Log Out" OnClick="LogOut_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

And

```
protected void LogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["user"] = null;
}
```